# Open external app inside cordova for ios, android and windows

Tags: android, ios, cordova, android-intent, deep-linking

Is there a way to simply open an other app in a cordova application and if the app is not installed, forward on the store. This request for ios, android and windows phone.

I am searching this on google but is not clear between intent, deeplinking, url scheme, ... And it look there is not complete solution...
How should i do it ?
Moreover, if we need the urlscheme or id of the other app, how can i exactly find it ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there is no easy way to do this without the cooperation of other app.

**Chrome Intents** and **Custom URL Schemes** are two different methods to do *deep linking*. Two other terms you may come across are **App Links** and **Universal Links*.

### Chrome Intents

Work within Google Chrome on both iOS and Android. A limited number of other apps (for example, Firefox) also support this approach. This is a custom — and unnecessarily complex, in my opinion — approach cooked up by the Chromium team at Google that basically specifies both app and fallback destination information inside the same request. However it relies on the source application to properly parse it, otherwise it will fail. In other words, not a good option for a complete solution.

### Custom URL Schemes

Previously the de facto standard for deep linking. Unfortunately all good things must eventually come to an end, and Apple basically killed URL scheme deep linking in iOS 9.2. Long-term, this is probably good for the ecosystem because it solves a lot of problems that were starting to come up with scheme collisions, but it's still a headache for app developers in the short-term. There is no easy way to handle situations in which your app isn't installed, because attempting to open a custom URL scheme that isn't registered on a device will lead to an error page. **URL schemes are still supported on Android.** I'm not as familiar with the deep linking ecosystem on Windows Phone because it is so small, but I believe it is also based around custom URL schemes.

### Universal Links & App Links

Essentially the same technology: **Universal Links** is the iOS implementation, and **App Links** is the Android version. These work by creating a verified connection between your normal website URLs and your app. If your app is installed, the OS will intercept the website request and instead open your app. This is much easier to authenticate than a URL scheme, because only one person can control and verify a given domain, and a website URL is an automatic fallback destination if your app isn't installed. However, this can be a big limitation if you don't *have* a corresponding website. These are also not supported everywhere yet.

---

To get a comprehensive approach, you need to handle all of these standards along with several others, and then be prepared to handle a huge number of complicated edge cases. A Cordova app is even worse, because you'll need to deal with edge cases on both iOS and Android *within the same app*. To open another app and reliably fall back to the app store when it isn't installed, you need that other app to do all of the above and then provide you with specs for their implementation — not an easy task.

At [Branch.io](https://branch.io/) *(full disclosure: I'm obviously on the team)* we provide all of the above as a free service, and actually facilitated an app-to-app collaboration exactly like this between Yummly and Instacart. You can read about the specs in [this case study](https://branch.io/case-studies/yummly/).

Comment: Great explanation thanks.
So finally for both platform we have different way to manage it.
Also you tell that it will open on other app or web site that we get. But is it also possible to open app from an other app ? I don't now, for example opening facebook from gmail if I am owner of gmail ? (of course is not the case ^^, actually... xD)